# Aggregate function that selects the value of a column that corresponds to another successful aggregate functions match

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry about the bad subject. I couldn't think of a better one and I'm in a hurry.

Say i have the following tables:

**Parent**

- Id
- Name
- ...

**Child**

- Id
- ParentId
- Age
- ...

There is a One-to-Many relation between parent and child.

Now I want to construct a query that returns all parents and their youngest child. I want the result to be like this:

**Result**

- Parent.Id
- Child.Id
- Child.Age

There should also be only one row per Parent.Id in the result.

Here is an image that explains what i want

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6PjL.png]

This is where I am right now:

```
SELECT   
Parent.Id AS ParentId,
Child.Id AS ChildId, 
MIN(Child.Age) AS ChildAge -- OVER (PARTITION BY Parent.Id) AS ChildAge
FROM Parent JOIN Child ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
GROUP BY Parent.Id, Child.Id
```

What I would want is an aggregate function to put around Child.Id that would fetch the Child.Id that corresponds to the row that is MIN(Child.Age). I can't find any such thing and i can't seem to emulate the behavior.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The system required you to have a certain amount of reputation before allowing inline images, but I'm sure it won't be long till you do have that. I have edited to bring your image inline for you.

Comment: Yeah it told me so. Reasonable. Thanks for the edit! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea of using `OVER` with a `PARTITION BY ParentId` is in the right direction; however, rather than use it with `MIN`, use it with a `ROW_NUMBER()` to get at the whole row. This:

```
SELECT
    ParentId
    , Id
    , Age
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY Age ) AS rn
FROM Child
```

returns all children, along with a row number indicating their age order *within children of the same parent*, so we just need to filter that:

```
SELECT ParentId, Id, Age FROM (
    SELECT
        ParentId
        , Id
        , Age
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY Age ) AS rn
    FROM Child
) c   -- need to alias the subquery in order to SELECT from it
WHERE rn = 1


ParentId    Id          Age
----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          2
2           13          4
3           15          3
4           19          1
```

**Note** that while you ask for "all parents and their youngest child", you may want to consider what you want returned for records in `Parent` with *no* matching records in `Child` - my solution, along with all the others, will not include any information about such `Parent` records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   
Parent.Id AS ParentId,
C.Id AS ChildId, 
C.Age AS ChildAge 
FROM Parent, CHILD C
WHERE PARENT.ID = C.ParentId
AND C.AGE = 
(
    SELECT MIN(AGE)
    FROM CHILD
    WHERE ParentId = C.ParentId

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   
    Parent.Id AS ParentId,
    Child.Id  AS ChildId, 
    Child.Age AS ChildAge 
FROM Parent
  JOIN Child 
    ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
  JOIN
    ( SELECT ParentId,
             MIN(Age) AS ChildAge
      FROM Child
      GROUP BY ParentId   
    ) AS minCh
    ON Child.ParentId = minCh.ParentId
    AND Child.Age = minCh.ChildAge
```

Answer (score -1):

This one might work:

```
SELECT
ParentID,
ChildId,
ChildAge
FROM
(

SELECT   
Parent.Id AS ParentId,
Child.Id AS ChildId, 
MIN(Child.Age) AS ChildAge,   
Ranking  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  ParentID order by Child.Age asc)  

FROM Parent JOIN Child ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
GROUP BY Parent.Id, Child.Id, Child.Age
)A
Where Ranking =1
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT parentid, id, age FROM child c
 WHERE age = (SELECT MIN(c2.age) FROM child c2 WHERE c2.parentid = c.parentid);
```

Note that you may find more than one child per parent (if they have the same, minimal age).

Comment: Recheck your query. It is not correct. "id" doesn't belong to child. There are other issues too.